# Splitting JSON ForEach to accommodate forSQL 1000 row INSERT limit

Tags: php, sql-server, json, foreach, insert

The code I have is working, but it doesn't look very efficient.  I'm hoping someone will have a better solution.  I'm pulling data from a JSON feed and then inserting that data into a MS SQL table.  The problem occured when there were more than 1000 rows coming from the JSON feed (MS SQL has a 1000 row limit on INSERT statements).  I would like to get this done with as few statements as possible.

This is what I have:

```
foreach($JSON as $pairGroup) {
        if ($i < 901){
            $rValues .= "(".$pairGroup->Group_A.",".$pairGroup->Group_B."),";
            $i++;
        }else if($i < 1801){
            $rValues2 .= "(".$pairGroup->Group_A.",".$pairGroup->Group_B."),";
            $i++;
        }
 }

$query = "INSERT INTO my_table (Group_A, Group_B) values".$rValues.";";
```

This is then followed by an if statement that basically creates another query with $rValues2, and so on.  Keep in mind, I could potentially have 20,000 - 30,000 rows that need to be inserted, so a viable solution needs to automatically accomodate for any number of rows.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: There is no row limit on `INSERT`.  It's the `VALUES` clause that is limited to 1000 rows, and this is a sign that you are using the wrong approach.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296157%28SQL.90%29.aspx